# How do I change the margin of Pandoc's markdown lists?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, pandoc

So, I have the following snipped:

```markdown
**Elektronenkonfigurationen:**

- F:  $1s^2 2s^2 2p^5$
- Cl: $1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^5$
- Br: $1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^6 4s^2 3d^{10} 4p^5$
- I:  $1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^6 4s^2 3d^{10} 4p^6 5s^2 4d^{10} 5p^5$
```

and it renders to this:

[image: Example rendered]

I use Pandoc as the converter and PDF as the output format.

Is there any way I could change the left margin of the bullet items? Preferably, I would want them to line up with the bold text above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load `enumitem` and control the spacing with `\setlist`:

```
---
header-includes: |
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist[itemize]{left=0pt}
...

**Elektronenkonfigurationen:**

- F:  $1s^2 2s^2 2p^5$
- Cl: $1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^5$
- Br: $1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^6 4s^2 3d^{10} 4p^5$
- I:  $1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^6 4s^2 3d^{10} 4p^6 5s^2 4d^{10} 5p^5$
```

[image]